# Rails "param is missing or the value is empty" error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, parameters, controller

I have this link_to helper passing an `:email_sequence` instance and an extra `:set_active` params.

I then try to update the `:email_sequence` instance in the controller using strong params but I'm getting an error saying:

```
param is missing or the value is empty: email_sequence
```

link_to:

```
<%= link_to "Activate", admin_email_sequence_path(base_email.email_sequence, set_active: :true), method: :patch %>
```

Controller:

```
class Admin::EmailSequencesController < AdminController
  before_action :set_email_sequence

  def update
    if @email_sequence.update(active: email_sequence_params[:set_active])
      flash[:success] = "Sequence updated succesfully"
      redirect_to_forwarder_or(params[:forwarding_uri], admin_account_emails_path)
    end
  end

  private

  def set_email_sequence
    @email_sequence = current_account.email_sequences.find(params[:id])
  end

  def email_sequence_params
    params.require(:email_sequence).permit(:set_active)
  end
end
```

This is what gets sent in the `params`:

```
{"_method"=>"patch", "authenticity_token"=>"[FILTERED]", "set_active"=>"false", "id"=>"1"}
```

Can anybody tell me what am I doing wrong?

Comment: The strong params are looking for `{email_sequence: {set_active: 'true'}}`.  you could remove the require and instead permit the params you want.

Answer (score 0):

By `params.require(:email_sequence).permit(:set_active)` you expect parameters to be `{ email_sequence: {set_active: "ANY SCALAR VALUE HERE"} }` but you pass only `set_active` you can fix it by permitting the only one parameter

```
params.permit(:set_active)
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need strong parameters here in the first place. Contrary to popular belief strong parameters does not magically sanitize the parameters. It just prevent mass assignment vulnerabilities by requiring that you whitelist the parameters when passing a hash of parameters. Since you are only using a single parameter there is no mass assignment vulnerability:

```
class Admin::EmailSequencesController < AdminController
  before_action :set_email_sequence

  def update
    if @email_sequence.update(active: params[:set_active])
      flash[:success] = "Sequence updated succesfully"
      redirect_to_forwarder_or(params[:forwarding_uri], admin_account_emails_path)
    else
      # provide an error response!
    end
  end

  private

  def set_email_sequence
    @email_sequence = current_account.email_sequences.find(params[:id])
  end
end
```

If you later want to use multiple parameters nested in a hash the use of `link_to` is pretty questionable even if it can be done.

```
<%= link_to "Activate", 
            admin_email_sequence_path(
               base_email.email_sequence, 
               "email_sequence[set_active]" => true, 
               "email_sequence[foo]" => "bar"
            ), 
            method: :patch 
%>
```

Use `button_to` or `form_with/form_for` to create a form element and style the button to look the way you want instead as this places the parameters in request body instead of the query string.